# Changing subtopics in BlazeDS and Flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

I using messaging in Flex-BlazeDS.  When the AIR client starts it connects to a destination and a specific subtopic.  During runtime, the user can use a combo box to subscribe to different sets of live data coming in, this combo box change event changes the subtopic by:

```
messagingConsumer.subtopic = subtopicComboBox.selectedLabel;
messagingProducer.subtopic = subtopicComboBox.selectedLabel;
messagingConsumer.subscribe();
```

A message is then sent to the server with the new subtopic name as well so the server knows to send to a new subtopic.

This whole mechanism seems very glitchy and I'm wondering if anyone else has tried this and succeeded?  Most times it works the first time and the after that either the messages dont get sent or I get server errors like:

[BlazeDS]Endpoint with id 'my-streaming-amf' cannot service the streaming request as either the supplied FlexClient id 'B07F3285-A408-816E-4697-F13F9B17E32C is not valid, or the FlexClient with that id is not valid.

Also sometimes when I change subtopics it will cause the FlexSession and FlexClient to be destroyed instead of just the MessageClient.  Once that FlexSession gets destroyed it messes up all kinds of things including logging out the user.

Perhaps I'm over complicating things by changing subtopics to listen to different sets of live data, if anyone has any other ideas on how to accomplish dynamic changing of destinations or subtopics please list those as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try and unsubscribe before you change the subtopic and resubscribe.

Comment: yes that did it.  Actually, I went a bit further and called disconnect() on the consumer and producer and then created a new instance of each.  Works now.